# Why running Android Lint on pipeline is giving different warnings?

Tags: android, lint, android-lint

I've enabled the Android Lint on my `app` module with config xml with these enabled rules, and also created a baseline.

```
lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError true
        ignoreTestSources true
        lintConfig rootProject.file('config/lint.xml')
        baseline file("${project.projectDir}/baselines/android-lint-baseline-${getCurrentFlavor()}.xml")
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="FindViewByIdCast" severity="error" />
    <issue id="MissingSuperCall" severity="error" />
    <issue id="UsesMinSdkAttributes" severity="error" />
    <issue id="AaptCrash" severity="error" />
    <issue id="GradleCompatible" severity="error" />
    <issue id="HardcodedText" severity="error" />
    <issue id="RestrictedApi" severity="error" />

</lint>
```

When I run it locally by `gradle lintDebug` task, apparently it doesn't check for `RestrictedApi` rule, it doesn't register any `RestrictedApi` occurrence on baseline or gives the warning on console. But when I run it on the pipeline, using the same task, I get the following lint error:

```
Error: Fragment.getLayoutInflater can only be called from within the same library group prefix (referenced groupId=androidx.fragment with prefix androidx from groupId=android) [RestrictedApi]
              LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater(null);
```

If I run the `Code > Run Inspection By Name > Restricted Api` on the IDE, It will run on the release target and will find this occurrence.

What are the possibilities that I can check over? Why `lintDebug` and `lintRelease` gives different results?

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find a solution for your problem?